# Angular Date From Web API Response

Tags: angular, datetime, angular2-observables

I am developing an Angular (4.1.2) web application along with a corresponding ASP.Net Core (1.1) Web API.

I have an Angular service which makes an http request for data to my web API and the dates in the objects returned from the Angular service are not of type `Date`.

In my scenario my web application is getting `Tasks` from my SQL database and each `Task` includes a start and finish `DateTime`. My TasksController uses AutoMapper to map each `Task` to a `TaskViewModel` object and my `TaskViewModel` has a start and finish property which is of type `DateTime`.

If I put a break-point in my TasksController and examine the `TaskViewModel` objects to be returned, following the request, the start and finish properties are of type `DateTime` and as such the day, month, hour etc are all fine.

In Angular I have a `task-api.service.ts` file which includes the following code:

```js
public getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    let tasksArray: Observable<Task[]> = this.http.get("/api/tasks").map((response: Response) => {
        return <Task[]>response.json();
    }).catch(this.handleError);

    tasksArray.forEach(item => {
        console.log("Start: " +
            item.map(task => {

                if (task.start instanceof Date) {
                    console.log(task.start + " is date.");
                } else {
                    console.log(task.start + " is not date.");
                }

            }));
    });

    return tasksArray;
}
```

When I `console.log()` the start and finish date they appear like `2017-01-01T1 0:00:00`. I tested the dates to check them.

My Angular `Task` class is defined like this:

```js
export class Task {

private _children: Task[];

get children(): Task[] {
    //console.log("Getting children");
    return this._children;
};
set children(value: Task[]) {
    //console.log("Setting children");
    this._children = value;
};

constructor(
    public id: string,
    public scheduleId: string,
    public description: string,
    public taskTypeId: number,
    public taskType: string,
    public locationId?: number,
    public start?: Date,
    public finish?: Date,
    public duration?: number, // milliseconds
    public parentId?: string,
    public dependentTaskId?: string,
    public label?: string,
    children?: Task[])
    {
        if (children != null)
        {
            this.children = children;
        };
    }
};
```

How do I ensure that the start and finish dates in my Typescript objects are of type `Date` please?

Comment: Why you want to check the response type is date? You can convert to the type as what you want. right?

Comment: I was only checking the type to help me investigate why the dates weren't being understood by my business logic code which was using the dates. The start and finish properties in my observable array of Tasks were just strings of letters and numbers, not Dates so my business logic couldn't work with them.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am experiencing the same thing. Date received from web api has undefined values for getMonth, getFullYear etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dateReviver?

```
public getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    let tasksArray: Observable<Task[]> = this.http.get("/api/tasks")
                .map((response: Response) => {
                        return <Task[]>JSON.parse(response, dateReviver);
                }).catch(this.handleError);
}

function dateReviver(key, value) {  
    var a;  
    if (typeof value === 'string') {  
        a = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*)?)Z$/.exec(value);  
        if (a) {  
            return new Date(Date.UTC(+a[1], +a[2] - 1, +a[3], +a[4],  
                        +a[5], +a[6]));  
            }  
    }  
   return value;
};
```

NOTE: Careful with date time kind. UTC or Local.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/json-parse-function-javascript

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/04/12/native-json-in-ie8-firefox-3-5-plus-json-net